# Creating a stock index etc. from a large data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, stock

I have a data frame namned `stockdata`, which includes the close prices of several stocks over several years. The style of the data frame is presented below:

```
      date close  ticker  stock.name
2001-09-06  3.06  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-07  2.89  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-09  2.67  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-10  2.67  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-11  2.56  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-12  2.24  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-13  2.44  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-06 20.70  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-07 20.60  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-09 20.40  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-10 20.50  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-11 20.50  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-12 20.70  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2001-09-13 20.60  MEAB   Malmbergs Elektriska
2011-07-06 1.8018 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-07 1.8018 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-08 1.8318 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-11 1.8394 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-12 1.8394 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-13 1.8769 HTRO   Hexatronic
```

From this I would like to:

1. Add a column namned `percentage`, which should contain the stocks' performance in percentage based on the first listing date of each stock.
2. Create a stock index based all the stocks' close price in the data frame. Since the amount of stocks vary by time (different introduction dates, delistings etc.), this needs to be considered when calculating the percentage and price for the new stock index.

Which would be the easiest way to perform these things? Is there any way without having to loop through all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
date close  ticker  stock.name
2001-09-06  3.06  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-07  2.89  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-09  2.67  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-10  2.67  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-11  2.56  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-12  2.24  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-13  2.44  LAGR   Lagercrantz
2001-09-06 20.70  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-07 20.60  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-09 20.40  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-10 20.50  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-11 20.50  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-12 20.70  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2001-09-13 20.60  MEAB   'Malmbergs Elektriska'
2011-07-06 1.8018 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-07 1.8018 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-08 1.8318 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-11 1.8394 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-12 1.8394 HTRO   Hexatronic
2011-07-13 1.8769 HTRO   Hexatronic
  ",
  header = TRUE)
```

**1. and 2.**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(
    percentage = close / close[date == min(date)],
    average = mean(percentage))
```

Comment: Thank you Tony!

Regarding question 2, I guess I just need the average of the stocks' new column "percentage "

Comment: And you want the averages of the `percentage` column to be grouped by ticker still, right? I edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: I have tested the code @tonybot, and the percentage works well. However the average just creates a straight line horizontal line if I were to plot the data (when the stock data is actually fluctuating a lot). 

I think I need to create a new vector for the average, and make sure that there is only one available value for each date. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I solved the the average problem @tonybot by creating a new tibble, and using the summarise function. Thank you for all the help! :)